# Let Intellij IDEA always show parameter tooltip

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

Is there a way to tell Intellij IDEA 14 to always show the parameter tooltip that appears when you start writing a function? The problem is that the "bubble" disappears when you exit the parentheses and doesn't show up again when you re-enter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know there is no configuration option to always display the parameter tooltip. However you can invoke it manually when you reenter the method using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Mac).

---

**References**

- [IntelliJ Help: Viewing Method Parameter Information](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/viewing-method-parameter-information.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think JetBrains should change this default behavior, or at least add an option for it.

For now, here are some workarounds:

- Use <kbd>**CTRL**</kbd><kbd>**P**</kbd> or make a custom key binding such as <kbd>**CTRL**</kbd><kbd>**;**</kbd>.
- Settings / Keymaps / Parameter Info / **Add Mouse Shortcut**.
- Delete and then retype the opening parenthesis.